# How do I run a command line program as Administrator under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sudo, administrator

How do I run a command line program as Administrator under Windows 7?  (Like `sudo` on Linux.)

I'm particularly interested in doing this, for a VS2010 command line program.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc771525%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is to right click cmd.exe, and select the option "Run as Administrator".

It's possible you may get a dialog box asking if you're sure, and if you are, select Ok. You now have admin access to the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Type command in the search box in the start menu, right click command prompt and select run as administrator.
Alternatively, start menu, type cmd, press ctrl+shift+enter.